# emacs projectile - "you are not in a project" displayed when in directory

Tags: emacs, projectile

I've just created a new folder of javascript files.

The structure is:

```
.gitignore
README.md
build
node_modules
package.json
src
webpack.config.js
```

But when I try and find a file with `C-c p f`, I get a message in the status bar that states

> You're not in a project

I have other projects with the same structure that work fine so I don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think your project is indeed considered a project by `projectile` only if you have a `.git` folder in it (did you forget to `git init`?). I'm not seeing one in your case. You can alternatively add a `.projectile` file instead. Everything in that folder containing the `.projectile` file and all subfolders will be considered part of the same project.

Answer (score 2):

Simply open any file in the git project using C-x C-f and then try running command C-c p f.

Opening a file in a git project will make projectile recognize the project.

> Just open some file in a version-controlled (e.g. git) or a project
>   (e.g. maven) directory that's recognized by Projectile and you're
>   ready for action.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: I know this post is now old but since I encountered a similar issue
today, it seems to me relevant to share my notes about it, taking care of users not too familiar with emacs lisp.

---

The culprit *function* is likely `projectile-project-root`.

You can try to investigate about it with

- `C-h f` or `(describe-function 'projectile-project-root)`
- `C-h v` or `(describe-variable 'projectile-require-project-root)`

The help screen provides a link to the *elisp source code* which you could step through using `debug-on-entry` (see info node "Debugging" in elisp)

This function uses caching so this might be somewhat uneasy, depending on your skills with emacs lisp.

---

**Workaround:**

I solved my case by moving my project to another directory, suspecting that its name starting with "test" may have caused the problem. I also removed project cache subdirs (check hidden as well).